# Can I block phone numbers based on the area code, preferably without an app?

Tags: android-11, call-screening, google-pixel-4a

I have a Pixel 4a, on Android 11.

Can I block phone numbers based on an area code? Preferably without an app, but happy to use an app if it's necessary.

Comment: Close to what you are asking using [automation](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172174/131553)